# Mysql can't write to filesystem

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I need to output some queries as csv files.  The directory is in the webroot and I want it to be writable by apache too, so I'm trying to add mysql to the www-data group (on Ubuntu).

I thought this would work, but I've missed something:

**Add mysql to www-data:**

```
ubuntu@168:~/viewer/files$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data mysql
```

**Restart mysql:**

```
ubuntu@168:~/viewer/files$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                       [ OK ] 
ubuntu@168:~/viewer/files$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                       [ OK ]
```

**Verify permissions:**

```
ubuntu@168:/var/www/html/viewer/files$ pwd
/var/www/html/viewer/files
ubuntu@168:/var/www/html/viewer/files$ ls -al
total 640
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu www-data   4096 Jun 10 18:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu www-data   4096 Jun 10 14:31 ..
```

**Verify group:**

```
ubuntu@168:~$ id mysql
uid=106(mysql) gid=112(mysql) groups=112(mysql),33(www-data)
```

I've restarted my session - no good.  A day later and my sql query still isn't able to write out:

```
mysql> SELECT id, title FROM recipes WHERE id IN ('R225037', 'R225046', 'R226412') INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/viewer/files/ingredient_caps_6-10-14.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/var/www/html/viewer/files/ingredient_caps_6-10-14.csv' (Errcode: 13)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile might be relevant

Comment: Double check it's in the group. Post the output of `id mysql`

Comment: @Dancrumb: that was totally it.  if you want to throw it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu apparmor doesn't let mysql write to directories other than listed in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

apparmor is enabled by default, but on dedicated MySQL servers I don't see much sense in it.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/apparmor.html: 
"AppArmor can be disabled, and the kernel module unloaded by entering the following:

```
    sudo service apparmor stop
    sudo update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
```

"